# Assistance with creating an UPDATE statement please

Tags: sql, sql-server

Very new to all things SQL so hopefully you can bear with me.

I have a situation where I have data waiting in a staging table that has around 11 columns and 100 rows. The destination table contains around 27 columns and also 100 rows.

I am trying to create a Server Agent job using T-SQL scripting to update the destination table from the staging table, but only for the columns required.

```
Staging Table
Col1 - Col11

Destination Table
Col1 - Col27
```

I need to preserve the 'surplus' column in the destination table as they hold data not supplied by the staging table.

I should also point out that number of records in the staging table will continue to grow over time and the schedule for the Agent job will look to the staging table every hour for updates.

This is my script at the moment, which does complete successfully but every row in the destination table is populated by the data in the 1st row of the staging table.

> e.g. Staging Table Col1 = David and Col2 = Smith.

Once the query below is executed, all rows in the destination table contain David and Smith in Columns 1 and 2 for every record.

```
UPDATE DestTable
SET DestTable.Col1 = StagingTable.Col1,
    DestTable.Col2 = StagingTable.Col2,
FROM StagingTable
```

I had considered using a `WHERE` statement to match ID data but for any new records waiting in the staging table, the ID wouldn't be 'known' by the destination table.

Lastly, the staging table will offer the destination table new records, updates to existing records, and also records to be deleted.

Thanks in advance, and apologies for the 'essay'.

Comment: First thing you should do is determine by which columns you are comparing. Provide some minified example of staging and target table and the result you are looking for.

Comment: Slightly off topic --> If your staging table contains new rows that you wish to add to your destination table you have a couple of choices.  You can execute serperate [UPDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) and [INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) statements.  Or you could look into [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb510625.aspx) queries, these can be a little daunting at first but they do allow you combine the update and insert into one statement.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do some more digging around the MERGE option I think.

Comment: Thanks to you all, the MERGE option seems to be the way to go (I just need to work out how to ignore NULL values now!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `UPDATE` statement combined with an `INNER JOIN` between the `StagingTable` and `DestTable` should give you the behavior you want:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.Col1 = t2.Col1,
    t1.Col2 = t2.Col2
FROM DestTable t1
INNER JOIN StagingTable t2 ON (t1.Col1 = t2.Col1 AND t1.Col2 = t2.Col2)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, I have tried your query but I am getting the dreaded multi-part identifier could not be bound.

Comment: Try it again, sorry about this.  This error is not so dreadful anymore, thanks to Stack Overflow ^ ^.

Comment: Thanks again Tim, I'm still having a few issues but your revised query is executing correctly. The only issue now is that the results tell me that no rows were affected, even though I know the data in col1 and col2 are completely different in both tables.